# Trailing data in Laravel when submitting form

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I created an expense form in Laravel and tried to submit it for the data to be inserted into the database but after submitting this error got displayed:

Error displayed with screenshot

[image]

```
  C:\xampp\htdocs\Tailor\core\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Carbon.php
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     *
     * @return static
     */
    public static function createFromFormat($format, $time, $tz = null)
    {
        if ($tz !== null) {
            $dt = parent::createFromFormat($format, $time, static::safeCreateDateTimeZone($tz));
        } else {
            $dt = parent::createFromFormat($format, $time);
        }

        static::setLastErrors($lastErrors = parent::getLastErrors());

        if ($dt instanceof DateTime) {
            return static::instance($dt);
        }

        throw new InvalidArgumentException(implode(PHP_EOL, $lastErrors['errors']));
    }

    /**
     * Set last errors.
     *
     * @param array $lastErrors
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private static function setLastErrors(array $lastErrors)
    {
        static::$lastErrors = $lastErrors;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getLastErrors()
    {
        return static::$lastErrors;
Arguments
"Trailing data"
```

I have tried all the possible ways I knew I could even searched through the net still couldn't find a solution to this problem.

I have been on it for the past hours.

Here is the create.blade

```
<div class="portlet light bordered">
    <h3 class="page-title">Expenses</h3>
    {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'url' => ['admin/save']]) !!}
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Create
        </div>    
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('expenses_category_id', 'Expense Category*', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                    {!! Form::select('expenses_category_id', $expenses_categories, old('expenses_category_id'), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                    @if($errors->has('expenses_category_id'))
                        <p class="help-block">
                            {{ $errors->first('expenses_category_id') }}
                        </p>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('entry_date', 'Entry date*', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                    {!! Form::text('entry_date', old('entry_date'), ['class' => 'form-control date dpicker', 'placeholder' => '']) !!}
                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                    @if($errors->has('entry_date'))
                        <p class="help-block">
                            {{ $errors->first('entry_date') }}
                        </p>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('amount', 'Amount*', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                    {!! Form::text('amount', old('amount'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '']) !!}
                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                    @if($errors->has('amount'))
                        <p class="help-block">
                            {{ $errors->first('amount') }}
                        </p>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    {!! Form::submit('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
```

The ExpensesController

```
public function store(StoreExpensesRequest $request)
    {
        Expense::create($request->all());

        return redirect('admin/expenses');
    }
```

The Expense Model

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

/**
 * Class Expense
 *
 * @package App
 * @property string $expenses_category
 * @property string $entry_date
 * @property decimal $amount
*/
class Expense extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = ['entry_date', 'amount', 'expenses_category_id'];

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        Expense::observe(new \App\Observers\UserActionsObserver);
    }


    /**
     * Set to null if empty
     * @param $input
     */
    public function setExpensesCategoryIdAttribute($input)
    {
        $this->attributes['expenses_category_id'] = $input ? $input : null;
    }/**
     * Set attribute to date format
     * @param $input
     */
    public function setEntryDateAttribute($input)
    {
        if ($input != null) {
            $this->attributes['entry_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat(config('app.date_format'), $input)->format('Y-m-d');
        } else {
            $this->attributes['entry_date'] = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get attribute from date format
     * @param $input
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEntryDateAttribute($input)
    {
        $zeroDate = str_replace(['Y', 'm', 'd'], ['0000', '00', '00'], config('app.date_format'));

        if ($input != $zeroDate && $input != null) {
            return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $input)->format(config('app.date_format'));
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }

    public function expenses_category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ExpensesCategory::class, 'expenses_category_id')->withTrashed();
    }

}
```

the web.php

```
Route::post('/save', 'ExpensesController@store');
```

Comment: What is the exact error message? "Trailing data" is not an error message.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin, I have added the full error been displayed.

Comment: Put `dd($request->entry_date);` in the beginning of the `store` method. What does it show?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin, do you mean this way:                                          public function store(StoreExpensesRequest $request)
    {
  dd($request->entry_date);
        Expense::create($request->all());

        return redirect('admin/expenses');
    }

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin, this is what was been displayed: "2018-02-04 07:54:27"

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin, so, what should I do?

Comment: You haven't shown the error message. You've shown a method from Carbon package. If you're not sure about how the error message looks like, please make a screenshot of the page with the error. Also, show full `Expense` model.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin, please check it out. I have updated it. Thanks.

Comment: The probem is definitely in the mutator or the accessor. Load the form. Then please put `info('set'); info($input)'` to `setEntryDateAttribute` as the very first line and `info('get'); info($input);` to `getEntryDateAttribute`. Then submit the form. Check `storate/logs/laravel.log` file and post the last few lines after each `set` and/or `get`.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin, [2018-02-04 15:07:00] local.INFO: 2018-02-04 07:54:27  
[2018-02-04 15:07:00] local.ERROR: Trailing data {"userId":9,"email":"jcameron@gmail.com","exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Trailing data at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Tailor\\core\\vendor\
esbot\\carbon\\src\\Carbon\\Carbon.php:582)
[stacktrace]

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin, #0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Tailor\\core\\app\\Expense.php(45): Carbon\\Carbon::createFromFormat(NULL, '2018-02-04 07:5...')
#1 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Tailor\\core\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Concerns\\HasAttributes.php(525): App\\Expense->setEntryDateAttribute('2018-02-04 07:5...')

Comment: Please make a screenshot.

Comment: Also, do you have `date_format` in the `config/app.php`? What does `dd(config('app.date_format'));` show?

Comment: Use `parse` instead of `createFromFormat`.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin, Thanks for your help. it is working perfectly now. I deleted both the setEntryDateAttribute and getEntryDateAttribute

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why but sometimes the html form returns the data with seconds at the end `...example 2020-01-01T10:10:10...` sometimes not `example 2020-01-01T10:10`.

To solve it, I made a `substr($date,0,16).":00"` and thus avoid overflowing the format size that Carbon requires.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I fix the Carbon error by adding the following method to my (base) model.

```
public function getDateFormat()
{
     return 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u';
}
```

If you are using TIME WITH TIMEZONE in Postgres then the format should be:

```
Y-m-d H:i:s.uO
```